# Await db.SaveChangesAsync(); creating error -> Store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of rows (0)

Tags: asp.net-mvc, visual-studio

I am trying to put delete button to delete uploaded photo in edit.cshtml view. The error its showing me is

```
store update, insert, or delete statement affected an unexpected number of zero rows (0) in ef5 on line await db.SaveChangesAsync();
```

I have tried everything but the code doesn't work.

I'm not able to find the solution

This is my blogscontroller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Drawing.Drawing2D;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Net;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Mvc;
using System.Web.WebPages;
using Bloggengine.Models;

namespace Bloggengine.Controllers
{
    [Authorize]
    public class BlogsController : Controller
    {
        private MyDbContext db = new MyDbContext();

        // GET: Blogs
        public async Task<ActionResult> Index()
        {
            return View(await db.Blogs.ToListAsync());
        }

        // GET: Blogs/Details/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Details(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new 
            HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Blogs blogs = await db.Blogs.FindAsync(id);
            if (blogs == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(blogs);
        }

        // GET: Blogs/Create
        [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult Create()
        {
            return View();
        }

        // POST: Blogs/Create
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the 
        specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
        LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Create([Bind(Include = 
        "Blog_Id,Title,Author,Images,Content,L_id")] Blogs blogs)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Blogs.Add(blogs);
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            ModelState.Clear();
            return View(blogs);
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Add(Blogs blogs)
        {
            string filename = 
            Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(blogs.Imagefile.FileName);
            string extension = 
            Path.GetExtension(blogs.Imagefile.FileName);
            filename = filename + DateTime.Now.ToString("yymmssff") + 
            extension;
            blogs.Images = "~/Image/" + filename;
            filename = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("~/Image/"), 
            filename);
            blogs.Imagefile.SaveAs(filename);
            db.Blogs.Add(blogs);
            db.SaveChanges();
            ModelState.Clear();
            ViewBag.Message = "Blog Successfully Created.";
            return View("Create", blogs);
        }

        // GET: Blogs/Edit/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new 
            HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Blogs blogs = await db.Blogs.FindAsync(id);

            if (blogs == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(blogs);
        }

        // POST: Blogs/Edit/5
        // To protect from overposting attacks, please enable the 
         specific properties you want to bind to, for 
        // more details see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/? 
        LinkId=317598.
        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> Edit([Bind(Include = 
        "Blog_Id,Title,Author,Images,Content,L_id")] Blogs blogs)
        {
            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                db.Entry(blogs).State = EntityState.Modified;
                await db.SaveChangesAsync();
                return RedirectToAction("Index");
            }
            return View(blogs);
        }



        [HttpPost]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public ActionResult DeletePhoto(string Images)
        {
            var fullPath = Server.MapPath("~/Image/" + Images);

            if (System.IO.File.Exists(fullPath))
            {
                System.IO.File.Delete(fullPath);
                ViewBag.message = "File deleted";

            }
            else
            {
                ViewBag.message = "Photo isn't uploaded.";
            }

            return View();
        }


        // GET: Blogs/Delete/5
        public async Task<ActionResult> Delete(int? id)
        {
            if (id == null)
            {
                return new 
             HttpStatusCodeResult(HttpStatusCode.BadRequest);
            }
            Blogs blogs = await db.Blogs.FindAsync(id);
            if (blogs == null)
            {
                return HttpNotFound();
            }
            return View(blogs);
        }

        // POST: Blogs/Delete/5
        [HttpPost, ActionName("Delete")]
        [ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
        public async Task<ActionResult> DeleteConfirmed(int id)
        {
            Blogs blogs = await db.Blogs.FindAsync(id);
            db.Blogs.Remove(blogs);
            await db.SaveChangesAsync();
            return RedirectToAction("Index");
        }

        protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
        {
            if (disposing)
            {
                db.Dispose();
            }
            base.Dispose(disposing);
        }
    }
}
```

This is my edit.cshtml view

```
@model Bloggengine.Models.Blogs


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Blogs</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @if (ViewBag.message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">@ViewBag.Message</div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class 
      = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = 
      new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { 
     @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { 
       @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = 
       new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { 
      @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Images, htmlAttributes: new { 
        @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("DeletePhoto", 
          "Blogs")">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Images)" width="100" 
            height="100" />
                <input type="submit" name="Images" value="Delete" 
          class="tiny button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { 
      @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes 
       = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { 
       @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

And this is my blog model

```
@model Bloggengine.Models.Blogs


@using (Html.BeginForm())
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()

<div class="form-horizontal">
    <h4>Blogs</h4>
    <hr />
    @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })

    @if (ViewBag.message != null)
    {
        <div class="alert alert-success">@ViewBag.Message</div>
    }
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Title, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Title, new { htmlAttributes = 
       new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Title, "", new { 
        @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Author, htmlAttributes: new { 
       @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Author, new { htmlAttributes = 
       new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Author, "", new { 
      @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Images, htmlAttributes: new { 
        @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            <form method="post" action="@Url.Action("DeletePhoto", 
        "Blogs")">
                <img src="@Url.Content(Model.Images)" width="100" 
     height="100" />
                <input type="submit" name="Images" value="Delete" 
    class="tiny button">
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Content, htmlAttributes: new { 
     @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
        <div class="col-md-10">
            @Html.EditorFor(model => model.Content, new { htmlAttributes 
      = new { @class = "form-control" } })
            @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Content, "", new { 
   @class = "text-danger" })
        </div>
    </div>

    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="col-md-offset-2 col-md-10">
            <input type="submit" value="Save" class="btn btn-default" />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
}

<div>
    @Html.ActionLink("Back to List", "Index")
</div>

@section Scripts {
    @Scripts.Render("~/bundles/jqueryval")
}
```

Comment: Could you please determine where exactly did you get the error?
**Blogs blogs = await db.Blogs.FindAsync(id);    db.Blogs.Remove(blogs);         await db.SaveChangesAsync();**
The possible option is in input **id** is **Null**. Hence you can not fetch the related data and finally, you could not remove it.
Before all, check the **id** which has value or not.

Comment: i got the error on await.db.savechangesasync();

Comment: good. so this time check the input **id** value. it must not be null

Comment: Is it solved? your welcome...if it was. give me an up vote  :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is while updating the *Blog*, *Blog_Id* is not getting post, because of you have not set any field with the value of it.
So, add a hidden field with the value of *Blog_Id* in your *Edit.cshtml* view, Like:

```
@Html.HiddenFor(model => model.Blog_Id)
```